# Javascript split, push and join

Tags: javascript, join, split, push

How come the `|` is not added when I call the join method

```
    var array ="12|23|435|566|46|6|666766|24";
    var arraySplit = array.split("|");
    var newArray = [];
    for (i=0; i<arraySplit.length; i++)
    {
        if (arraySplit[i] < 500)
        {
            newArray.push(arraySplit[i]);
        }
    }
    newArray.join("|");
    alert(newArray);
```

Comment: Have a look at MDN's documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`newArray.join` does not modify the existing array. It returns a new string of all the array's current values, joined by the string you specify. Use the following to store the generated array in a new variable:

```
var joinedArray = newArray.join("|");
alert(joinedArray);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/EH8dB/

---

**References:**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: @ruakh Haha very good point. I didn't think of that - I was just going off the original question, which seemed to expect that the variable `newArray` would become a string of the joined values.

Answer (score 1):

You are not modifying newArray since join() returns a new object.